# Date format error SQL Server 2000+ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have been successfully created new module in my system (localhost) but when I patched into server it having a problem on dateformat. As I noticed by default SQL Server will store in `mm/dd/yy`. For localhost the date was stored in `mm/dd/yy` (correct) but it reflected when I patch in server to `dd/mm/yy`.

Here is my code

```
SQL = "Insert into tbl(Date) value ('" & Date & "')
```

someone please help me..thanks

Comment: SQL Server **doesn't** store the date in any particular *format* - it's stored as two 4-byte integers, really. But the language settings and date format settings come into play when **converting** from a string to a date - you should use the ISO-8601 format `YYYYMMDD` which will work for **all** dateformat and language settings

Answer (score 4):

Your server probably has different localization settings than your localhost.

Try formatting the date value in the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, which won't be misinterpreted.